# Install Kubuntu on SSD following failed Windows reinstallation?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

**Update(3/20/21):** Created a new primary partition on the disk via Windows command line and made sure it was in GPT mode, but still couldn't install Windows.  My guess is that Windows might still be looking at my HDD as the install location, and disconnecting it for the installation would require me getting a little further into my computer's case than I'm comfortable doing right now.  In the end I decided to just go with Kubuntu only(at least for now).  I consider the problem solved for my purposes, but don't feel comfortable marking this as "answered" when my solution doesn't really answer the original question.

**Update(3/19/21):** Was able to get into the Windows command line via the installer USB and was able to [change the SSD to an MBR partition format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-gpt-disk-into-an-mbr-disk).  Kubuntu now recognizes the SSD(sda) as a valid install location, but Windows doesn't yet.  It appears the Microsoft guide neglects to mention the need to create a new primary partition after cleaning the disk, so I'll report back with results after trying that.

**Original(3/18/21):** Relatively beginner-level dual-booter and Linux user here.  First off, some details on my setup:

- 225GB SSD (partitioned between Windows 10 and Ubuntu Studio 20.04)
- 1TB HDD (programs and files)
- If it's at all relevant: 32GB RAM, 3.5GHz AMD CPU.

I've had problems with major Windows 10 updates for close to a year; the April/May '20 update was never able to install correctly and at some point(October '20 update I suspect), Windows quit booting normally and started going into its Recovery Environment.  System Restore doesn't work because there are no restore points.  All the other troubleshooting options don't work because they involve rebooting the computer, which just sends me back to GRUB.  It's been this way for at least a month.  I figure reinstalling Windows and repartitioning the SSD is the best course of action.  I picked the option to "fully clean the drive"; Windows gets about 30-40% into its process and then brings up an error message saying "There was a problem repairing your computer."  I didn't think much of it at the time(this was last night) so I just thought I'd work on it again in the morning.

When I woke up and turned the computer on again, the UEFI gave me the standard "insert boot media" message when trying to boot from my SSD.  Looking through the file system, what I suppose happened is that Windows began wiping the drive, deleted both OS, then couldn't reinstall and left me with nothing.  I boot up using the Kubuntu USB I made -- at this point I'm planning to just install Kubuntu and forget about Windows -- but now my HDD is the only install location available.  Running **lsblk** gets the following results:

```
loop0    7:0    0   1.8G  1 loop /rofs
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   223G  0 part /media/kubuntu/Windows
└─sda4   8:4    0   450M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 931.5G  0 part /media/kubuntu/Blade
sdc      8:32   1  28.7G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   1   2.5G  0 part /cdrom
├─sdc2   8:34   1   4.9M  0 part 
├─sdc3   8:35   1   300K  0 part 
└─sdc4   8:36   1  26.1G  0 part /var/crash
```

And running **df -h** gets:

```
tmpfs                        3.2G  9.6M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdc1                    2.6G  2.6G     0 100% /cdrom
/cow                          16G  238M   16G   2% /
/dev/disk/by-label/writable   26G   49M   25G   1% /var/log
tmpfs                         16G   92M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                         16G  504K   16G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                        3.2G   80K  3.2G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sdb2                    932G  407G  525G  44% /media/kubuntu/Blade
/dev/sda3                    224G   15G  209G   7% /media/kubuntu/Windows
```

So it looks like the SSD(sda) is still being recognized, at least -- but why can't I install to it?  Looking at other questions, it looks like this sometimes happens because the SSD is in RAID mode instead of AHCI, but I don't think that's the problem -- when I look in the UEFI the boot options for both drives are already labeled with AHCI.

**TL;DR** since I probably included a lot of extraneous information: Windows wiped my SSD and both operating systems, but won't install.  I'm making this post using the Kubuntu Live USB, and still have my Windows USB in case it's necessary for any fixes.

I would vastly prefer to fix the SSD so that I can install Kubuntu on there, but if it had to be I would be okay with installing to the HDD for now and then looking into fixing the SSD later on.  My main reason for keeping Windows was access to Steam games, but if I can run them through WINE/PlayOnLinux I really don't care about keeping Windows anymore.

Comment: Is this an UEFI system. Drives gpt partitioned? UEFI & SSD firmware updated? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Yes, it's a UEFI system.  After looking into this and past problems my computer has had with Windows updates, I believe the underlying problem is the fact that the SSD is GPT partitioned as opposed to MBR.  I'm not sure how to update the UEFI & SSD firmware, so I can't give you a solid answer on that.

Here is the pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6Knz68sgkc/

Comment: Your sdb2 is one issue. While it says ok, that is that grub can (but should not) be installed to a PBR - partition boot sector/record. But you never install grub to NTFS as Windows has vital info in the PBR. You need to see if you can restore from backup PBR. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix Report is not showing /EFI/Boot or /EFI/Microsoft or /EFI/ubuntu? Are those folders in your ESP, sda1? Be sure to always boot in UEFI boot mode. And use Windows tools to shrink a NTFS partitions to make room for / (root) partition. Others can be on HDD then.

Comment: @oldfred I don't quite understand why sdb2 would be the problem -- it's my HDD, where I have only files and certain Windows programs stored.  I never installed GRUB there(unless it happened without my knowledge, like in an update or something).  The instance of GRUB it's finding there is inside the Kubuntu ISO.  Will deleting the ISO help?  The three /EFI/ folders don't exist currently since Windows' reinstaller deleted everything on the drive.

Comment: You then will need to reinstall Windows UEFI boot files with a Windows repair/recovery flash drive in UEFI mode. And totally reinstall grub with Ubuntu live installer  in UEFI boot mode and/or Boot-Repair's advanced mode to choose full reinstall. If you install grub to Windows PBR, then Windows sees it as unformatted or "RAW".

Comment: @oldfred Unfortunately this is the problem -- every time I try to use the recovery drive to repair Windows it simply says that it can't and sends me back to the troubleshooting menu.  Is there a way to do it through the command line?

Comment: Not sure if it is looking at sdb2, but that still needs to be resolved. You might disconnect sdb and then see if Windows works as it will not see defective NTFS. You do have to boot Windows repair/recovery drive in correct UEFI boot mode to make UEFI repairs.

Comment: @oldfred  I have been making sure to boot the recovery drive in UEFI mode.  Disconnecting sdb presents a problem as that involves getting a bit further into my computer’s case than I’m comfortable with at the moment.  I need to get this machine working soon, so I may just have to install Kubuntu on the cleaned SSD(sda).  Will sdb2 still be a problem then?  Should I clean that drive as well?

Comment: If using UEFI, use gpt partitioning. Windows requried gpt, Ubuntu does not but should. If SSD not seen update SSD firmware, update UEFI and check settings in UEFI are AHCI for that drive.

Comment: @oldfred SSD and UEFI are up to date.  Cleaned the disk and changed the partition table to GPT, still no luck with Windows installing.  My guess is that it might still be looking at sdb as an install location, but as I mentioned earlier I'm not comfortable opening the computer enough to disconnect it.  I decided to forget about Windows and just go ahead with Kubuntu for now, which is fine for my purposes.  However I don't feel like it would be correct to mark this as "answered" because my solution ended up being dumping Windows altogether.  Thank you for all the help, though!